# Show |f(z)|<|z| or if |f(z)|=|z|, then f is a rotation.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f \in H(\mathbb{D})$, i.e. $f$ is holomorphic on the unit disk, and  $f(0) = 0$ and $|f(z)|<1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$. Show that $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$, and if $|f(z)| = |z|$, then $f$ is a rotation $f(z) = \alpha z$ with $\alpha \in \partial \mathbb{D}$.

Comment: [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma)

Comment: Thanks! It took me hours trying to figure out a proof.

Comment: You're welcome :)